# Layout is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>. How should I overcome this error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

```
<Routes>
        <Route exact path='/'>
          <Layout>
            <Home></Home>
          </Layout>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
```

**Layout consists of header and footer, I want to wrap my home inside Layout.**

*React 18.1.0*

*react-router-dom 6.0.2*

[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other `Route` components are the only valid children of a `Route` component. This is the use case of building nested routes. For routed content/components, these must use the `element` prop.

Render the `Layout` component ***as*** the `element` of the `Route` component.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path='/'
    element={(
      <Layout>
        <Home />
      </Layout>
    )}
  />
</Routes>
```

It also common to have layout components render an `Outlet` for nested routes.

Example:

```
const Layout = () => (
  <>
    <Header />
    <Outlet />
    <Footer />
  </>
);
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<Layout />}>
    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just extract the `<Home/>` component from there and provide the layout as a prop to the Route like this

```
<Route component={Layout} />
```

And provide your home component inside the Layout component it self

Comment: OP is using `react-router-dom@6`. The `Route` components don't have a `component` prop.

Comment: Oh, I didn't check the version I'm sorry.